# Table2Excel JS showing warning message that file format & extension don't match when we open an Excel sheet

Tags: java, jquery, excel

Table2Excel JS showing warning message that file format & extension don't match when we open an Excel sheet

Below the steps to reproduce:

1. we have used table2excel JS (https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel) for converting HTML data in Excel sheet.
2. We are successfully converted dynamic data in excel sheet but when we try to open(after downloading) that excel sheet we are getting some warning message i.e. file format & extension don't match.
3. Please refer the below screenshot for the same:

   [image]
4. Is there any proper way to convert HTML data to excel sheet without getting such warning message.
5. Also most of the App in mobile devices like in IOS, Microsoft excel, office suit, Polaris are unable to open the file only WPS Office is opening the file.
6. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This is the default behavior. [table2excel#disclaimer](https://github.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel#disclaimer): "This plugin is a hack on a hack. The .xls extension is the only way [some versions] of excel will even open it, and you will get a warning about the contents which can be ignored. "

Comment: There are other libraries that can produce excel files like https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx or https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs (which are the first 2 result on a google search of _js library_). If you are using a java backend you can also use POI for creating the excel file.